# Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

So I have been trying to make a horizontal bar chart from DF in Python. I succeeded but the values in X-axis arent in the right order.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.xlim(0, 14)

# data
people = (a.Ethnicity)
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = a.Value

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Value')
ax.set_title('Unemployment between different ethnic groups in 2004')

plt.show()
```

This code gives me the below graph:
[Graph from Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65W1B.png)

But I want it to be something like this: [This graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n00AG.png)
Or something like this: [Graph from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6L7m.png)

This is the variable a:

```
a = df.loc[(df.Time == 2018) & (df.Region == "All") & (df.Age == "All") & (df.Sex == "All"), ["Ethnicity","Value"]]
print(a)
                      Ethnicity Value
32772                        All   4.2
32952                      Asian   6.2
33132                Asian Other   6.1
33312                      Black   8.8
33492                     Indian   4.3
33672                      Mixed     7
33852                      Other   7.5
34032           Other than White   7.1
34212  Pakistani and Bangladeshi   8.4
34392                    Unknown   4.1
34572                      White   3.7
34752              White British   3.8
34932                White Other   3.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code in my editor and got the graph you want. Values in the X-axis are in the correct order. It looks to me as there is some sort of incorrect sorting happening maybe in another part of your code. I copied your data as a dictionary to create the dataframe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlim(0, 100)

data = {'All': 4.2,
        'Asian': 6.2,
        'Asian Other': 6.1,
        'Black': 8.8,
        'Indian': 4.3,
        'Mixed': 7,
        'Other': 7.5,
        'Other than White': 7.1,
        'Pakistani and Bangladeshi': 8.4,
        'Unknown': 4.1,
        'White': 3.7,
        'White British': 3.8,
        'White Other': 3.4}

a = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=["Ethnicity", "Value"])
people = (a.Ethnicity)
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = a.Value

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Value')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Graph]

Comment: That works. But that's because it was from the dictionary. But how do I do that from dataframe?

Comment: Your Y-axis values in your graph are coincidentally in the same order as the dataframe you printed in your question. Try resetting the index of the dataframe and see if it changes anything. If not, then you could look into `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`, a function which allows you to convert a dataframe to a dictionary and then plot that.